# How to fetch email account details with Python IMAP?

Tags: python, gmail, imap

After logging in to my Gmail account with the Python imaplib module, I would like to retrieve my account details e.g. email address or my screen-name. I haven't found any obvious method to do so in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html). Is there such a method?

*PS: As seen in the email and user-name is returned after log in (example below). I suspected it would be stored in some attributes.*

```
>>> import imaplib
>>> mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
>>> mail.login('myusername@gmail.com', 'mypassword')
('OK', ['myusername@gmail.com Benjamin T. authenticated (Success)'])
```

Comment: There isn't a method for that in IMAP, but I won't make this an answer because I can't say for sure that Gmail didn't add an extension.